# PHP html_entity_decode for non-breaking hyphen (&#8209;)

Tags: php, encoding, html-entities

I am attempting to decode the following string, then save the contents to a file.

Using PHP, Apache on Windows 64-bit.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$String = "<p>This is a non&#8209;breaking hyphen</p>";
$Data = html_entity_decode($String, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
file_put_contents("result.txt",$Data);
?>
```

*result.txt in Notepad :*

[image]

*result.txt in Notepad++ :*

[image]

Is there a way to get the non-breaking hyphen to appear correctly in both editors?
Or am I missing some fundamentals?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: change encoding of editor (Notepad ++ )

Comment: Its what npp reads its client side

Comment: Notepad++ already in UTF-8